# Sample in R with a maximum condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, sample

In order to evaluate my students in petrography, I need to create boxes of 2 different rocks and the students need to recognize them. I want to write a R script to assign rocks to each box.

This is how I did :

```
rocks <- c("granite","pumice","gneiss","marl","chalk")
samp <- NULL
for (i in 1:24) {
    samp <- sample(rocks,2)
    
    if (i==1) {
       box <- samp
    } else {
      box <- rbind(box,samp)
    }
}
```

Which works perfectly

```
box
[,1]      [,2]     
"granite" "gneiss" 
"marl"    "chalk"  
"granite" "gneiss" 
"pumice"  "marl"
"chalk"   "granite"
"gneiss"  "granite"
"pumice"  "chalk"  
"gneiss"  "marl"   
"gneiss"  "pumice" 
"gneiss"  "pumice" 
"pumice"  "gneiss" 
"pumice"  "marl"
"marl"    "chalk"
"granite" "gneiss" 
"granite" "chalk" 
"gneiss"  "granite"
"pumice"  "granite"
"pumice"  "chalk"
"pumice"  "granite"
"gneiss"  "pumice" 
"pumice"  "granite"
"granite" "marl" 
"marl"    "gneiss" 
"pumice"  "gneiss"
```

However, I have only 3 samples for the rocks "chalk" and "marl".  Therefore, the dataframe *box* that I generated is not feasible.

How can I get my script to only generate 3 samples of "chalk" and "marl"?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you show us your expected output? Or one such possible output.

Comment: Do you mean that `marl` and `chalk` only can appear at most 3 times?

Comment: That's correct @R18

Comment: @user2974951 I provided the table I got. What I want is to have the same table with maximum 3 occurences of both "chalk" and "marl"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not the most elegant way, but this should do it:

```
rocks <- c("granite","pumice","gneiss","marl","chalk")
samp <- NULL
nb.chalk = 0
nb.marl = 0
for (i in 1:24) {
  # bad.sample: when 3 rocks from chalk and marl were already attributed but still sampled
  bad.sample = TRUE
  while (bad.sample){
    samp <- sample(rocks,2)
    bad.sample = (nb.chalk == 3 & 'chalk' %in% samp) | (nb.marl == 3 & 'marl'  %in% samp)
  }
  # count the numbers of chalk and marl already obtained
  if ('chalk'  %in% samp) nb.chalk = nb.chalk +1
  if ('marl'  %in% samp) nb.marl = nb.marl +1
  
  if (i==1) {
    box <- samp
  } else {
    box <- rbind(box,samp)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution without a for loop:

```r
library(tidyverse)

rox <- bind_rows(
tibble(rox = c("marl","chalk")) %>% 
  split(.$rox) %>% 
  map_df(~.x %>% slice(rep(row_number(), 3))),

tibble(rox = c("granite","pumice","gneiss")) %>% 
  split(.$rox) %>% 
  map_df(~.x %>% slice(rep(row_number(), 10)))
)

box <- rox %>% 
  sample_n(24, replace = F) %>% 
  bind_cols(rox %>% 
              sample_n(24, replace = F)) %>% 
  rename(box_1 = 1, box_2 = 2)

table(box$box_1)
#> 
#>   chalk  gneiss granite  pumice 
#>       1       9       7       7
table(box$box_2)
#> 
#>   chalk  gneiss granite    marl  pumice 
#>       1       8       8       1       6
```

Comment: Great I love using tidyverse !

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to start with an inventory of the rocks available, then assign non-matching pairs to shuffled students.

This ensures the constrained rocks are fully utilised.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Set rocks available
rocks_available <- tribble(
  ~rock, ~constraint,
  "granite", 14,
  "pumice", 14,
  "gneiss", 14,
  "marl", 3,
  "chalk", 3
) |> 
  uncount(constraint)

# Assign shuffled rocks
boxed <- rocks_available |> 
  group_by(rock) |> 
  mutate(rock_id = row_number()) |> 
  arrange(rock_id) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  select(-rock_id) |> 
  mutate(student = rep(1:24, each = 2),
         pick = if_else(row_number() %% 2 == 1, "one", "two")) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = pick, names_prefix = "pick_", values_from = rock) |> 
  mutate(student = permute::shuffle(student))

# Peak in the boxes
boxed |> head()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   student pick_one pick_two
#>     <int> <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1      20 granite  pumice  
#> 2       6 gneiss   marl    
#> 3      22 chalk    granite 
#> 4       9 pumice   gneiss  
#> 5      19 marl     chalk   
#> 6      24 granite  pumice
  
# Verify rocks boxed
boxed |> 
  pivot_longer(-student) |> 
  count(value)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   value       n
#>   <chr>   <int>
#> 1 chalk       3
#> 2 gneiss     14
#> 3 granite    14
#> 4 marl        3
#> 5 pumice     14
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>